# How to modify an array of objects to group by most recent year?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I currently have an array of objects like so:

```
const array = [
  { key: 'model_1', year: 2019, displayOrder: 1},
  { key: 'model_1', year: 2018, displayOrder: 2},
  { key: 'model_2', year: 2018, displayOrder: 3},
  { key: 'model_3', year: 2018, displayOrder: 4},
  { key: 'model_4', year: 2019, displayOrder: 5},
  { key: 'model_5', year: 2018, displayOrder: 6},
];
```

I am trying to generate a new array that groups the objects by `current` and `previous` year and orders by `displayOrder`. If we applied this to the above array it would look like this:

```
const array = {
  current: [
    { key: 'model_1', year: 2019, displayOrder: 1 },
    { key: 'model_2', year: 2018, displayOrder: 3 },
    { key: 'model_3', year: 2018, displayOrder: 4 },
    { key: 'model_4', year: 2019, displayOrder: 5 },
    { key: 'model_5', year: 2018, displayOrder: 6 },
  ],
  previous: [
    { key: 'model_1', year: 2018, displayOrder: 2 },
    { key: 'model_4', year: 2018, displayOrder: 7 },
  ],
};
```

The theory behind this is that it should show the current version of the model. That will be based on the most recent year for the model.

I have attempted this by creating a reducing function that groups them by year, but I don't think this is the right approach as there could be a lot of overhead than to modify this further.

```
const modelsByYear = array.reduce((acc, model) => {
  acc[model.year] = acc[model.year] || [];
  acc[model.year].push(model);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));
```

What are some suggestions on how I can do this?

EDIT:

The reason I need this is for filtering. If I click on `current` or `previous` I need to see the respective models.

Comment: What distinguishes them from being a current or previous model?

Comment: Whichever year is the most recent. E.g. if one model has two years the most recent year is the current model. The second year would then go into previous. If one model has only one-year thats the current model. It basically depends on if the same model has two different year versions.

Comment: If the example code is supposed to have the latest version of each unique model in `current`, shouldn't "model_5" be in `current` as well?

Comment: @Robert model_5 should also be in current.

Comment: it should be. updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the key and splice ither the current array or push to the `previous` array.

```js
const array = [{ key: 'model_1', year: 2019, displayOrder: 1 }, { key: 'model_1', year: 2018, displayOrder: 2 }, { key: 'model_2', year: 2018, displayOrder: 3 }, { key: 'model_3', year: 2018, displayOrder: 4 }, { key: 'model_4', year: 2019, displayOrder: 5 }, { key: 'model_5', year: 2018, displayOrder: 6 }, { key: 'model_4', year: 2018, displayOrder: 7 }],
    grouped = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.current.findIndex(({ key }) => o.key === key);
        if (index !== -1) {
            if (r.current[index].year > o.year) {
                r.previous.push(o);
                return r;
            }
            r.previous.push(r.current.splice(index, 1)[0]);
        }
        r.current.push(o);
        return r;
    }, { current: [], previous: [] });

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I decided to go with this approach as it worked exactly how I require. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Considering there is a typo in output, i.e

```
{ key: 'model_5', year: 2018, displayOrder: 6 }
```

Should be present in current(as per comment of op).
You can try the following:

Sort the array based on key in descending order , year in ascending order and display order in ascending order. After that you can simply iterate over the list and get the desired result. Try the following:

```js
const array = [
  { key: 'model_1', year: 2019, displayOrder: 1},
  { key: 'model_1', year: 2018, displayOrder: 2},
  { key: 'model_2', year: 2018, displayOrder: 3},
  { key: 'model_3', year: 2018, displayOrder: 4},
  { key: 'model_4', year: 2019, displayOrder: 5},
  { key: 'model_5', year: 2018, displayOrder: 6},
];
array.sort((a,b)=> a.key.localeCompare(b.key) || b.year - a.year|| a.displayOrder - b.displayOrder);

var result = {
  "current" : [],
  "previous" : []
};

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(i == 0 || result.current[result.current.length-1].key != array[i].key){
    result.current.push(array[i]);
  } else{
    result.previous.push(array[i]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: did you check your code? It does not generate the desired output (however I admit that the description seems to conflict with the expected output).

Comment: @karelG according to op comment model_5 should be in current, there is a typo in output provided by op